# odoo - include xml for base model in xml of extending models

Tags: inheritance, odoo, odoo-view

Odoo lets you extend models easily using the `_inherit` field. Common code and fields of the base model can thus be accessed in extending models.

My question is: can I structure my xml files (e.g. search views, form views, etc.) of the extending models to also reuse common xml code of the base models?

I have read that the template include mechanism (using `t-call`) does only work for QWeb templates, but not in general for xml views (see [include templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45973115/how-to-include-view-in-odoo-8)).
And the view inheritance using `inherit_id` as I understand, only extends an existing view for a given model. However it does not make it possible to include parts of existing views to create a new one.

So does this mean I have to copy the common xml code for fields in the base model to all views that extend this model?

Example:

**Model inheritance**

```
class Base(models.Model):
    _name = 'bla.base'
    common1 = fields.Text()
    common2 = fields.Text()

class ExtA(models.Model):
    _name = 'bla.exta'
    _inherit = ['bla.base']
    field_x = fields.Integer()

class ExtB(models.Model):
    _name = 'bla.extb'
    _inherit = ['bla.base']
    field_y = fields.Integer()
```

**Views**

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="exta_search">
    <field name="name">exta.search</field>
    <field name="model">bla.exta</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <search>
            <field name="field_x"/>
            <!-- Also include xml to search in base model -->
        </search>
    </field>
</record>

<record model="ir.ui.view" id="extb_search">
    <field name="name">extb.search</field>
    <field name="model">bla.extb</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <search>
            <field name="field_y"/>
            <!-- Also include xml to search in base model -->
        </search>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: What about `_inherits` (delegation) inheritance instead? View inheritance will work there. An example is Odoo's models product.template and product.product.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a view inheritance possibility, but not with `t-call` which is for templates like printable documents or client view templates. The model `ir.ui.view` which is used for model views has a field `inherit_id`. Use that to extend origin views or already extended views. There a lot of examples in Odoo default apps.

Example: The module/app base has the model `res.partner` and form view with external id `view_partner_form`. Assumed you have extended the model with a new field `function2` which should be showed right after the `function` field, you have to extend the view:

```xml
<record id="view_partner_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">extended by function2 short example</field>
    <field name="model">res.partner</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form" /> <!-- here the inheritance happens -->
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="function" position="after">
            <field name="function2" />
        </field>
        <!-- the same extension but with xpath instead -->
        <!-- <xpath expr="//field[@name='function']" position="after">
            <field name="function2" />
        </field> -->
    </field>
</record>
```

`ref` needs an external id of the view you want to extend/inherit. If the ID is from another module, prepend the module name like in the example.

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. Using inherit_id in xml it is only possible to extend an existing view. However what I am trying to do is to create separate views for the models ExtA and ExtB, but with common xml code externalized and included where needed.
Furthermore it is possible in the python code to inherit from multiple models and mixins. The xml views do not provide such powerful mechanisms. It's a pity. Only option I see is copy and paste the xml parts, which results in redundant code in the views.

Comment: Yes, sorry i saw the model inheritance a bit too late. Never tried something like that, but i fear you are right :-(